# Check if value exists in an object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write the code of following algorithm

- I have an array of `active_id` (array)
- `ID` coming from url (string)
- if value of ID does not exist in active_id array

  - run the function A()
- else do nothing.

**Note** - function A() should be run only once.

I tried writing the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < activeIds.length; i++) {
    if (activeIds[i] != uid) {
         A();  //This is running multiple times.
    }
```

I tried using while loop

```
var i = 0;
while (activeIds[i] != uid) {
     A();  //This is running multiple times again.
    i++;
}
```

There is something i am missing. not able to figure it out.

Comment: Can you a add  a fiddle link. People will be able to help you more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use indexOf function which will return -1 if element is not exist on array and positive number start 0 till array (length -1) if element exist:

```
if (activeIds.indexOf(uid) == -1) {
    A();  
}

function A();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf`, like this:

```
if( activeIds.indexOf(id) < 0 ) A();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke `function A()` only if the a particular ID (`uid`) does not exist in your array `activeIds`, you may want to alter your loop approach with this:

```
if (activeIds.filter(function(n){ return n===uid }).length==0){
    A();
}
```

Where you have a definition of function A() ready to use already.

**Side note** You syntax with `function A(){}` is just defining the function A but it's not going to run it. If you want to define and run it once, you may do:

```
(function A(){
   // logic goes here
})();
```

Comment: I think [*every*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.every) fits better: `activeIds.every(function(v){return v != uid})`.

Comment: Just to make sure it works even if the browsers don't support ES6 feature.  I'm not sure if `activeIds.some(function(n){ return n===uid })` would produce better performance. Just wondering if it breaks as soon as it hits a truthy case.

Comment: I thought too much BTW. Elements are just primitive numbers. :)

Comment: *filter* and *every* are ES5 features. Only IE8 needs a shim…

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.indexof()` function in order to find the value.
It will look something like that:

```
if(activeIds.indexOf(uid) === -1){
    A();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, code.

```
var i=0;
var isMatchFound = false;

while (activeIds.length >= i) {
  if(activeIds[i] ==uid){
    isMatchFound = true;
    break;
}
 i++;
}

if(isMatchFound){
   //Call Function A
    A();
}
```

Hope this will help